# Battery Health Charging app on my Asus GL552VX

Tags: battery, asus-laptop, charging

I can't change options in Asus Battery Health Charging app on my Asus GL552VX notebook

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1489660/asus-battery-health-care-i-cant-choose-any-mode

Answer (score 1):

ASUS homepage says..

- ASUS Battery Health Charging is available on ASUS ZenBook models launched in 2017 or later.

https://techinstyle.asus.com/asus-battery-health-charging-helps-you-get-the-most-out-of-your-zenbook/   <- bottom of this page

Answer (score 0):

Try to instal all drivers from Asus [site](https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center).

Enter your model and your BIOS model name. To find the BIOS model name type in Comand Prompt `WMIC CSPRODUCT GET NAME`. ATK drivers are important, this utility enables the PC to communicate with all the attached hardware devices. Also, contact their support to give you the latest `Asus Health Battery Charging` or ask them if it is supported by your laptop.

Answer (score -1):

I installed the Battery Health charging app on my old asus laptop, and in order to work and be able to change the options you need to do the following:

- Open registry and browse to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ASUS\ASUS Battery Health Charging
- Modify dword CheckSupported from 1 to 0
- Reboot your system

Now you should be able to choose any of the options within the app.