# Asus Battery Health care : I can't choose any mode

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop, charging

I just bought an old asus K73SD laptop. 
Its battery only charges up to 56%, and then stops charging. 
After a few researches on the net, I found the "Asus battery health care" program, and installed it. 
My problem is, I can't change anything in it; the three options, " Full capacity", "Balanced mode" and "Maximum lifespan mode" are there **but** I am unable to choose one. 
I would like help, I'm really stuck with it and I want my laptop to charge up to 100%...
Have a good day,

Answer (score 1):

A battery loses capacity all its life, every year.
This is called [Capacity loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_loss).

Some Capacity loss is due to the number of recharging cycles.
A high-end lithium-polymer battery can lose about 20 percent of its capacity
after 1000 charge cycles.

Batteries degrade even if you don't use them. According to testing, a fully
charged lithium-ion battery will lose about 20 percent of its capacity after
a year of storage, and if stored in a warm place that number can increase
to 35 percent.

There is no way to fix an old battery and return it to 100% capacity.
In my opinion you need a new battery.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DWORD you can change to set the charging rate (just as if you were selecting it inside the app.

I am one of the people who, even by installing the ATK Package and editing the CheckSupported string, couldn't pick any options inside the app.

I then changed the DWORD string called ChargingRate to 32 (hexadecimal for 50), and even though the options are still faded inside the app, the charging rate is set to "Maximum Lifespan Mode".

[image: ASUS Battery Health Charging screenshot]

Comment: Could you edit this answer to show where to find the correct DWORD?

Comment: according to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1178597/733315) on superuser you can use a program called regscanner to find a key in the Windows Registry named `ChargingRate`. I used it and found a key. `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ASUS\ASUS System Control Interface\AsusOptimization\ASUS Keyboard Hotkeys` @andrew-morton

Answer (score 0):

1. download the ATK pack from the ASUS website and install it
2. in regedit find key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ASUS\ASUS Battery Health Charging
3. change CheckSupported from "1" to "0"
4. reboot
5. now all options in  Asus battery health enabled for change

ps: checked on asus n551jb

Answer (score 0):

56% would be a strange limit to be imposed by a battery health / care system... and indeed the [information I've found](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1032726/) shows 60% as the limit:

[image]

> C. Maximum Lifespan Mode(Green color): Stops charging when power is above 60% and resumes charging when power is below 58%. This mode is recommended when the Notebook is always powered by AC adapter.

Are you sure that the value you're reading is the "*Charge Level*" (i.e: as reported by windows in the system tray), rather than the battery's "*Relative Capacity*" (relative to brand new)?

If it's the latter, then you should expect some degradation over time, especially if the battery has been abused.

---

In contrast, my VAIO laptop gives the following options: 100% (off), 80% and 50%.

[image: VAIO Battery Care]